# How to write a sql statement to split the rows into several parts and sum the time by part

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using sqlserver.

```
    Table A:
        -------------------------------------------------------
        | id    | starttime             |     endtime         |
        -------------------------------------------------------     
        | 9     | 2016-09-19 02:36:05   | 2016-09-19 03:02:16 |    
        | 9     | 2016-09-19 03:02:16   | 2016-09-19 09:26:15 |
        | 9     | 2016-09-19 09:26:15   | 2016-09-20 01:18:02 |

    Table B:
        ----------------------------------------
        |partno   |dayHourStart | dayHourEnd   |
        ----------------------------------------
        |3        |12:00:00.000 | 19:00:00.000 |
        |3        |22:00:00.000 | 23:59:59.000 |
        |3        |08:00:00.000 | 09:00:00.000 |
        |1        |19:00:00.000 | 22:00:00.000 |
        |1        |09:00:00.000 | 12:00:00.000 |
        |2        |00:00:00.000 | 08:00:00.000 |
```

Now,I want to split the rows of Table A into several parts, and sum the time  by part, according to the corresponding time range of every partno in Table B. so How to write a sql statement to get the results as follows:

```
   Anticipant Result table：
        --------------------------------------------------|
        | id     |partno           |  timeSum (minutes)   |
        |--------|-----------------|----------------------|
        | 9      | 101             |    200               |
        | 9      | 102             |    620               |
        | 9      | 103             |    860               |
```

Any ideas would be appreciated! thanks.

Comment: What's the id - partno connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems difficult to fix it by using sql statement, so I have written a procedure to solve this problem. Do you have any good ideas ? especially for sql statement.

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A] (
    [id] int NOT NULL ,
    [starttime] datetime NOT NULL ,
    [endtime] datetime NULL ,
    [status] int NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ([id], [starttime])
    )

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B] (
    [partno] int NULL ,
    [dayhourStart] varchar(255)  NULL ,
    [dayHourEnd] varchar(255)  NULL 
    )

   INSERT INTO [A] ([id], [starttime], [endtime], [status]) VALUES ('9', '2016-09-19 02:36:05.000', '2016-09-19 03:02:16.000', '1');
   INSERT INTO [A] ([id], [starttime], [endtime], [status]) VALUES ('9', '2016-09-19 03:02:16.000', '2016-09-19 09:26:15.000', '1');
   INSERT INTO [A] ([id], [starttime], [endtime], [status]) VALUES ('9', '2016-09-19 09:26:15.000', '2016-09-20 01:18:02.000', '1');

   INSERT INTO [B] ([partno], [dayhourStart], [dayHourEnd]) VALUES ('3', '12:00:00', '19:00:00');
   INSERT INTO [B] ([partno], [dayhourStart], [dayHourEnd]) VALUES ('3', '22:00:00', '23:59:59');
   INSERT INTO [B] ([partno], [dayhourStart], [dayHourEnd]) VALUES ('3', '19:00:00', '22:00:00');
   INSERT INTO [B] ([partno], [dayhourStart], [dayHourEnd]) VALUES ('1', '09:00:00', '12:00:00');
   INSERT INTO [B] ([partno], [dayhourStart], [dayHourEnd]) VALUES ('2', '00:00:00', '08:00:00');

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSumTimeByPart]
        AS
        BEGIN

          create table #resultTb(
                partno int,
                starttime datetime,
                endtime datetime,
                sumtime float
          )


           declare @id int,@starttime datetime,@endtime datetime;  
           declare @partno int,@dayHourStart VARCHAR(20),@dayHourEnd VARCHAR(20);  

          DECLARE  crs_data CURSOR for  SELECT id ,starttime ,endtime FROM a where status=1;            

          open crs_data ;
          FETCH next FROM crs_data into @id ,@starttime ,@endtime ; 

             WHILE(@@fetch_status=0) BEGIN 
                  --declare @daytimeStart datetime,@daytimeEnd datetime;
                    declare @daytimeStartStr VARCHAR(20),@daytimeEndStr VARCHAR(20);
                    set @daytimeStartStr = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@starttime,120);
                    set @daytimeEndStr = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@endtime,120);


                DECLARE @tempdate VARCHAR(20) = @daytimeStartStr; 

                   WHILE(DATEDIFF(ss, @tempdate, @daytimeEndStr) >= 0 ) BEGIN --iterate from @starttime to @endtime to get the day from it.

                                 DECLARE  crs_part CURSOR for  SELECT partno,dayHourStart,dayHourEnd FROM b ;
                                 open crs_part ;
                                 FETCH next FROM crs_part into @partno,@dayHourStart,@dayHourEnd;

                                 WHILE(@@fetch_status=0) BEGIN 
                                        declare @part_daytimeStart datetime,@part_daytimeEnd datetime;

                                    set @part_daytimeStart = Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@tempdate,120)+' '+@dayHourStart as datetime);
                                    set @part_daytimeEnd = Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@tempdate,120)+' '+@dayHourEnd as datetime);

                                    IF ( NOT(@part_daytimeStart > @endtime  or @part_daytimeEnd < @starttime ) ) BEGIN
                                    declare @startdate datetime,@enddate datetime;
                                    set @startdate  = (case when @part_daytimeStart>=@starttime and @part_daytimeStart<=@endtime then @part_daytimeStart else @starttime end); 
                                    set @enddate = (case when @part_daytimeEnd <= @endtime  and @part_daytimeEnd >= @starttime then @part_daytimeEnd  else @endtime end);

                                    INSERT into #resultTb(partno,starttime,endtime,sumtime) values (@partno,
                                    @startdate,@enddate, DATEDIFF(minute, @startdate, @enddate)     
                                );

                                        END

                                            FETCH next FROM crs_part into @partno,@dayHourStart,@dayHourEnd;

                                END   

                                CLOSE crs_part
                                DEALLOCATE crs_part;

                        set @tempdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd, 1, @tempdate),120);       

                END

                FETCH next FROM crs_data into @id ,@starttime ,@endtime ; 

           END

         SELECT * FROM #resultTb
          drop table #resultTb;

           CLOSE crs_data;
           DEALLOCATE crs_data;

        END
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, dealing with times and datetimes and overlaps.  Here is one method:

```
select a.id, b.partno,
       datediff(minute,
                (case when b.dayHourStart > cast(a.starttime as time) then b.dayHourStart
                      else cast(a.starttime as time)
                 end),
                (case when b.dayHourEnd < cast(a.endtime as time) then b.dayHourEnd
                      else cast(a.endtime as time)
                 end)
               ) as minutes
from a join
     b
     on cast(a.starttime as time) <= b.dayHourEnd and 
        cast(b.endtime as time) >= b.dayHourStart;
```

The only issue with this idea is the last of the rows for `A`.  This spans two days.  That just makes the calculation much more difficult.  You should split that row into two rows:

```
    | 9     | 2016-09-19 09:26:15   | 2016-09-19 23:59:59.000 |
    | 9     | 2016-09-20 00:00:00   | 2016-09-20 01:18:02 |
```

Comment: many thanks at first！the method you gave may not work. coz there may be several parts in a row in the table A，we should split a row into several parts within the corresponding time range in table B,and then sum it by grouping by the partno，</br>e.g. the row : 2016-09-19 03:02:16   | 2016-09-19 09:26:15 ,can be split into  (2016-09-19 03:02:16, 2016-09-19 08:00:00 ] (102),(2016-09-19 08:00:00,2016-09-19 09:26:15] (103)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, b.partno, age(a.endtime, a.starttime) from a, b
```

I think this should do it, at least on PostgreSQL, but you can fiddle with it.

Comment: I'm using sqlserver. can you write a sqlserver T-SQL statement ?

Comment: It should be the same, just with the datediff function instead of age. You can even specify that you want it in minutes, so datediff(minute, a.endtime, a.starttime).

Comment: there are several parts in a row from starttime to endtime in table A.and it needs to split the time range in a row.